# How to find element using contains in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can anyone please help me how to use contains in my xpath? My xpath changes all the time when projects are added, so I can't find element using xpath:

```
//*[@id="page-content-wrapper"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/h2
```

I am using the following command to click on my project:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("//*[contains(text(), '" + projName + "')]")).click();
```

It gives: Unable to locate element.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + projName + "')]")).click();

Comment: Please add HTML code of the element that you want to locate.

Answer (score 0):

You're not finding by ID, you're finding by XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + projName + "')]")).click();
```

That's also a **very** wide-open path. If projName appears **anywhere** on the page, it will click the first occurrence. It does not have to be a clickable button.